# GCDWebServer Version in wkWebView

Tags: ios, gcdwebserver

In wkWebView, which version of GCDWebServer framework is used. How can I get the version of GCDWebServer used in wkWebView.

I have already checked Info,plist in GCDWebServer framework but didn't find any variable in GCDWebServer to get Version.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/), then it's from Apple and has nothing to do with GCDWebServer.

The version of GCDWebServer as of 3.2.5 and earlier is not available from the `Info.plist` of the framework for historical reasons. There is therefore no way to know the version of GCDWebServer programatically.

In GCDWebServer 3.2.6 and later, the version is in the `Info.plist` file.